# Android MapView: Disable auto zoom

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have made an Android app that shows a MapView with two overlays, one MyLocationOverlay and one custom overlay. I am programmatically zooming and panning to what I want the map to show. It also auto pans to my current location.

The auto pan is moving the map away from what I want to show.

So my question is simply: How can I disable the auto pan?

Thanks,
Ola

Comment: In your overlay are you adding markers? If yes, MapView automatically tries to best fit to the ViewPort.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no default behavior with the `MyLocationOverlay`.  Are you putting a `Runnable` in the `runOnFirstFix()`?